# Multiplying a string so that it goes down a page vertically?

Tags: python, string

```
print(((height-2)\n)*frame)
```

I thought this should work, but instead I come up with the error

> unexpected character after line continuation character: <string>, line 3, pos 41

`frame` is a number, and this is supposed to repeat a character down a page a certain number of times.  Sorry if this is a stupid/silly question, I'm really new to programming.

Comment: You need to add the rest of your code for anyone to be able to find the error

Comment: `height-2` will return an `int` or a `float` at best, you should be casting that back to a string

Comment: If an answer helped you, you should select it as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax to multiple a string is `"x" * count` where `x` would be the characters you want to repeat and `count` the number of times. Your `\n` isn't quoted and Python is seeing the backslash as the line continuation character. So you need to make that `"\n"`. I'm also not sure what the `(height-2)` part is supposed to be, but you'll need to fix that syntax a bit for Python to like it.

Answer (score 2):

This treats a string as an iterable of characters, and adds a newline between each character:

```
def print_down(s):
    print("\n".join(s))
```

then you can call it line

```
>>> print_down("X" * 5)
X
X
X
X
X
```

If you really had to do it in one like, you could

```
print("\n".join("X" * 5))    # same result
```